# Entity Average Rating

Tags: 7, entities

I have **Player** (Entity) which is referenced on a **Match** (Content Type).

Now I'd like to **Rate** (from 0 to 10) the player for every match and get the **average rating**, can someone point me to the right solution.

Comment: do you got some advance?

Comment: It did work yes.

Comment: Well I'm happy for you ;-) good luck in your projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and use the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) or [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc).

From Views Calc module page:

> This module adds simple calculations to a views table.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug
> in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies
> numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines
> calculated rows).

You can found some screenshots here: [How can I show average votes of fivestar nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/155512/28275)

Comment: I'm not sure it will work if i have more than 1 player per match...

Comment: @khoy I think that this will work, just make a test and let me know

Comment: Okay i'll try both modules.

Comment: @khoy : which of both modules did you end up with? PS to Adrian: merci for promoting "Views Calc" ... again ... (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) Should you ever want to reuse screenprints, feel free to use the ones I included in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116054/how-can-i-show-average-votes-of-fivestar-nodes/155512#155512 ...